# iterating over a reversed sequence of numbers

Tags: python

Is this the best syntax that I can get to iterate over a sequence of numbers:

```
for num in range(1000).__reversed__():
    print i
```

How good is reversed(range(1000))? I think that it will generate a list and then iterate over the individual elements. Am I right?

Comment: You can use `for num in xrange(999, -1, -1): ...`.

Comment: I am using python3.2,
xrange is no longer there

Comment: Then, just use `range` instead of `xrange`. `range` does not generate a list in Python 3.x

Comment: `print i` raises a SyntaxError in Python 3.x.

Comment: ah! yes
    print (i)
it should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for num in xrange(999, -1, -1):
    print i
```

**Edit**: assuming you use `python3`, here is the slightly changed piece of code:

```
for num in range(999, -1, -1):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a *couple* of options. Firstly, you can use `reversed`, and thats one good way to do it. You can also use `range(999, -1, -1)`, (`xrange` if you're in python 2) to do it.

You can also do this, if you have a list `some_list[::-1]`.

Comment: range() is good that way but won't reversed(range(100)) generate a complete list and then iterate over?

Comment: @new-kid Well `[::` means that take everything`, and the `-1` means "reverse it".

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the step value as a negative number to iterate in reverse.

```
for num in range(999, -1, -1):
    print(num)
```